# VBA MS Word conditional formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word, conditional-statements

I have a VBA code that gives a value in a variable and then adds the variable in a document

```
Dim NoGFIs As Integer
NoGFIs = 1
ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="GFIs ", Value:=NoGFIs
```

and I used a conditional statement in the word document

```
No of GFIs: {DOCVARIABLE GFIs}
Check IF: {IF <<GFIs>> = 1 "ONE" "NOT ONE"
```

But the outcome shows that something is wrong:

```
No of GFIs: 1
Check IF: NOT ONE
```

It shows that the GFIs value gets out from the VBA to the document, but IF fails to evaluate it??
Has anyone seen anything like that before?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition seems to be wrong. Please try the below:

`{ IF { DOCVARIABLE GFIs \* MERGEFORMAT } = 1 "ONE" "NOT ONE"\* MERGEFORMAT }`

Also, did you notice the trailing space in your variable name `"GFIs "` in `ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="GFIs ", Value:=NoGFIs`?

Results:

[image: NOT ONE]  [image: ONE]